# How to make a ServerScript wait for a LocalScript to fire a RemoteEvent

Tags: lua, roblox, luau, roblox-studio

I've searched through loads of forum posts from the ROBLOX Developer Forum for any answer(s) to this, and I have had no luck finding an answer so I'm hoping you can help.

Basically I want to have a ServerScript (located ServerScriptService) wait for a LocalScript (located in a GUI Button) to fire a RemoteEvent (using FireServer) with the user's selected police division.

I currently only have One GUI button setup (Frontline Policing). The LocalScript can be found below;

**LocalScript**

```lua
local div = game.ReplicatedStorage.Events.divisionEvent

local button = script.Parent
local gui = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent

button.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    div:FireServer("Frontline")
    gui.Enabled = false
end)
```

TLDR - I am wondering if it's possible to get a ServerScript to wait for a LocalScript to fire a RemoveEvent with needed information.

I've done loads of Research through around 50-60 Roblox Developer Forum posts, and none of them are either;

- The Same Issue as mine.
- The Proper Resolution.
- Not even associated with my issue.

Comment: Is there a reason that using the [RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/events/remote) connection isn't enough for your purposes? Because when you attach a function to an event, it is effectively waiting for the client to fire.